# tns doctor, need the Android SDK Build-tools installed (Windows 10)

Tags: android, windows, nativescript

Regards

I am following the coursera course, but I am getting an error on: tns doctor
[image]

I have seen several posts on stackoverflow, but I have not found a solution.

I already checked my system variables:
[image]

I add my sdk in Android Studio
[image]
[image]

Please I need help, since I want to continue advancing but I don't know what else to do

Thank you very much in advance

Answer (score 0):

I found the answer, you have to install that version in sdk tools